# Resolving XDMP-DBDUPURI leads to XDMP-MULTIDBSTMT in Marklogic

Tags: xml, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to delete a document from my DB and i am getting the below error-

```
XDMP-DBDUPURI: xdmp:document-delete("/test/abc.xml") -- URI 
/test/abc.xml found in forests forest-1 and forest-2
```

When i tried to resolve it with below code-

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $doc := "/test/abc.xml"
let $forest-name := "forest-1"
let $query :=
    'xquery version "1.0-ml";
     declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
     xdmp:document-delete($URI)'
let $options := <options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><database>{xdmp:forest($forest-name)}</database></options>
return xdmp:eval($query,(xs:QName("URI"),$doc),$options)
```

I am getting the error as below-

```
XDMP-MULTIDBSTMT: xdmp:invoke("/MarkLogic/cpf/actions/failure-action.xqy", 
(xs:QName("trgr:uri"), "/test/abc.xml", xs:QName("trgr:trigger"), ...), 
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval"><isolation>same-statement</isolation><prevent-
deadlocks>...</prevent-deadlocks>...</options>) -- Cannot process different-
database requests with same-statement isolation
```

Any suggestions to resolve this ?

Answer (score 4):

In certain cases, `xdmp:eval` can default to `isolation` `same-transaction`, though none seem to be documented. You need to explicitly specify `different-transaction` as `isolation` option. E.g:

```
<options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
  <isolation>different-transaction</isolation>
  <database>{xdmp:forest($forest-name)}</database>
</options>
```

HTH!

Comment: Yes and it is pointing to In /MarkLogic/cpf/triggers/internal-cpf.xqy

Comment: Intriguing, you have CPF enabled. It might be easiest to temporarily disable CPF. Easiest way to do so is to unhook the triggers database from the content db (set it to none), then fix the DBDUPURI's, and then reconnect the triggers db. You can do that from the Admin UI.

Comment: Thanks it helped me. But now i ran into another issue. Somehow whenever my Trigger database is connected with my content database. The documents are getting duplicated everytime.

Comment: can you suggest something ?

Comment: Perhaps better to post a new question for this, and provide some more details about your setup. How did you try to fix the duplicate uris for instance? Maybe also share some more about your CPF configuration?